# How to remove endpoint interceptor in Apache Camel

Tags: java, apache-camel

For example we have such route with id "id".

```
       from("direct:third")
          .to("mock:bar")
          .to("mock:foo")
          .to("mock:result");
```

Also we have unit tests. Each tests adds its own interceptor to endpoints like this:

```
context.getRouteDefinition("id").adwiseWith(new RouteBuilder() {
   @Override
   public void configure() throws Exception {

       interceptSendToEndpoint("mock:foo").skipSendToOriginalEndpoint()
          .log("Bye World").to("mock:detour");

    }
});
```

**Is it possible to disable/remove interceptor** added in previous test method without reloading whole camel context? (application have a lot of routes and it takes pretty much time).

I found similar topic with answer of Ashwin Karpe, but was not able to make that answer work and have doubths about its correctness. http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/How-to-remove-interceptors-td4431339.html

**UPD**

We have few Spring configurations for unit or integration tests in XML. Camel configuration also is in XML. Some tests puts interceptors for endpoints which sets mocks or stops further routhing or skips original endpoint etc.
Due to this fact we are enforced to use DirtiesContext annotation to restart Spring and Camel contexts after each such test Class/method which adds interceptors.
Restart of context each time tooks 30 seconds and slow down all test build.
The plan is to use the same CamelContext over all tests with the same XML configuration without reloading context.
So we need the idea how to repair Camel Context on the run.

Thanks for help!

Comment: No its not possible, can you provide more details how you unit test, and how you re-use your context among your test methods. And how much slower/faster is it. And what version of Camel do you use.

Comment: Have you tried destroying the route and creating it again? Because you're applying an aspect to that route.

You could just, destroy the route by removing it from the context and then adding it again in another test case that doesn't have that advice.

Comment: @ Claus Ibsen Thank you for you comment! I've added some information.to original post. Unfortunately I forget to check the version of Camel today.

Comment: @Murasame Thanks for your help. Maybe you could help me to do it properly, please? Because I tried to remove routes and then add the same route definition, but it does not help. Maybe I'm adding route in wrong way?